# Como analizar un JSON entregado por una api que utiliza graphql en flutter?

Tags: flutter, graphql

Pensaba que era posible hacerlo de la forma convencional solo agregando los headers y query necesarios sin embargo cuando lo recibo este llega correctamente pero al intentar usar el metodo fromJson que hago en mi modelo este no funciona.

Comment: Bienvenido/a a SOes. Lecturas sugeridas: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 + https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour -> aquí aprendes el uso del sitio y de paso obtienes tu primera medalla. Saludos.